# Laravel not recognizing Request as Ajax when using Postman

Tags: ajax, laravel, rest, api, postman

When I make request from Postman application to a Laravel Application, the

`$request->ajax()` is not returning TRUE.

I'm also sending the `Accept: application/json` header in Postman, Still no luck.

**Postman Request Screenshot**:

[image: Postman Request Screenshot]

**Code Screenshot**

[image: Code Screenshot]

Comment: please don't put screenshots, instead paste the actual code

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add the header `X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest`

**The explanation**

If you track down the method `->ajax()` it goes through the following function:

```
    /**
     * Returns true if the request is a XMLHttpRequest.
     *
     * It works if your JavaScript library sets an X-Requested-With HTTP header.
     * It is known to work with common JavaScript frameworks:
     *
     * @see https://wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Ajax_frameworks#JavaScript
     *
     * @return bool true if the request is an XMLHttpRequest, false otherwise
     */
    public function isXmlHttpRequest()
    {
        return 'XMLHttpRequest' == $this->headers->get('X-Requested-With');
    }
```

Add the header `X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest` and then `$request->ajax()` will return `TRUE`.